# Why am I getting "Segmentation Fault"?

Tags: c

I've searched and tried many other answers to problems like mine, but I still don't get it, I don't know what I'm missing here. This program should simulate an auction, it's a game which the smaller "bid" wins. I've come up with this code, but when I use the strcpy and the char variable type, this segmentation error comes up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int func02(int venc, int nj, int max, int mod, float med, char *nome);
int lanc;

int main (void)
{

    lanc = func02(0, 36, 15, 0, 0, "nome");
    printf("%d", lanc);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int func02(int venc, int nj, int max, int mod, float med, char *nome)
{

    int lance;

    if (venc == 0) {
        strcpy(nome, "ceadf");
        lance = 4;
    }
    else {
        if ((med <= mod) && (venc >= mod)) {
            lance = mod++;
        }
        else {
            lance = venc++;
        }
    }
    return(lance);
}
```

Comment: `lanc = func02(0, 36, 15, 0, 0, "nome");` and then `strcpy(nome, "ceadf");` you can't do this

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). **Use the debugger** `gdb`

Comment: @RohanKumar please don't edit the style of the post, (like moving braces on their own line), it's not useful.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca: Ah, sorry. I would keep that in mind from next time ;)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I've compiled just like you've mentioned. The debugger I don't have because I'm using Putty to connect to a server running a Debian for educational purpose. Where do I paste the warnings from GCC?

Comment: You very probably have `gdb` on that Debian server. Correct your source code to have *no* warning at all. BTW you should consider installing some Linux distribution on your own computer (since Linux is great to learn programming, and later to do programming professionally)

Comment: 'The debugger I don't have' - you should stop trying to write programs.  You don't have enough tools.

Answer (score 3):

You have passed string literal `"nome"` to `func02()` and your are writing it.

String literals are read only, writing to them will lead to undefined behavior like segmentation failt

Answer (score 1):

You cant use the function strcpy to copy the string into a string literal.

Instead dynamically allocate your string and then call strcpy().

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first, when you are posting questions like this, it's better to show what line the code is crashing on, and preferably a backtrace. With that said, here's what's going on:

```
lanc = func02(0, 36, 15, 0, 0, "nome");
```

Here you are sending the constant string "nome" to `func02`.

```
strcpy(nome, "ceadf");
```

Here you are trying to copy "ceadf" into `nome`, which fails for two reasons:

1. `nome` is a constant string. You can't modify it.
2. Even if you *could* modify it, it's only five characters long (each letter in "nome" plus the null byte), and you're trying to copy six bytes into it (each letter of "ceadf" plus a null byte). This would be a memory issue even if you were working with a writable string. In general, I'd avoid the use of `strcpy`, as it makes it easy to make mistakes like this.